# #undef main gives no result

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, program-entry-point, undef

I'm working with MVisualC++ 2010 and when I try to undefine the "main", there's no result and the console launches as usual.  I was expecting some missing entry point error or something.
Why is that?

```
#undef main
int main()
{
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

main isn't a `#define` in the first place. Your `#undef` changes nothing at all.

`#define foo bar` tells the preprocessor "replace all occurences of foo with bar". 
`#undef foo` tells the preprocessor "foo has no special meaning anymore, leave it as is"

If you want a linker error, rename `main` to e.g. `main2`, or do e.g. this:

```
void foo();
int main() {
  foo();
}
```

This tells the compiler that a `foo` function exists (but not what it is). `main` tries to use it, so the linker will give an error when it can't find it.

Comment: So if I undef main while using SDL, I don't work with standard library, just with something that is implemented in SDL?

Comment: If someone tells you not to define main, it means "don't create a main function". The term define is not the same as `#define`, it means "create this function/variable"

Comment: On SDL, I don't use this, but I believe what it does is to use a #define to "rename" main. Your #undef would, in that case, cancel the renaming and SDL's own `main` would not be called.